# Firebase unity android app authentication not working

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

Issue: When I create a user manually using the Firebase console, I can't login with that new account in my unity app with the error `UserNotFound`. But when I register my user using my unity app I can login successfully.

Here is my code, can anyone see anything wrong with it?

```cs
using Firebase.Auth;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using TMPro;

public class SignInScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TextMeshProUGUI emailInput, passwordInput;

    public void Login(){
        FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(emailInput.text,passwordInput.text).ContinueWith((task=>{
            if(task.IsFaulted){
                Firebase.FirebaseException e = task.Exception.Flatten().InnerExceptions[0]
                    as Firebase.FirebaseException;
                print(emailInput.text);

                PrintErrorMessage((AuthError)e.ErrorCode);
                return;
            }
            if(task.IsCompleted){
                // print("User is LoGGed IN");
                //SceneChange();
                SceneManager.LoadScene("homeScene");
            }
        }));
    }

    public void RegisterUser(){
        if(emailInput.text.Equals("") || passwordInput.text.Equals("")){
            print("Please Enter a Email AND Pass to Register");
            return;
        }

        FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance.CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(emailInput.text,passwordInput.text).ContinueWith((task=>{ 
            if(task.IsCompleted){
                print("Registration Complete");
            } else {
                print("Registration Failed");
            }
        }));
    }

    void PrintErrorMessage(AuthError errorCode){
        string msg="";
        msg = errorCode.ToString();

        print(msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure when you make it in the firebase console that it is using the same instance

Comment: @BugFinder how to find that?

Comment: You need to check that the firebase app is using the same details as the console app you're using

Comment: Can you add your unity app's user registration code? Maybe the account types are different

Comment: @samthecodingman I have updated the code please check

Comment: Open your Firebase Console to the [Authentication tab](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/authentication/users). Then using your app, create a new user. Refresh the console tab, did the new user appear?

Comment: @samthecodingman yes it appears in the console

Comment: If that's the case, then I'm stumped. Can you replicate the problem from a web browser?

Comment: @samthecodingman in same project I have used firebase hosting and web authentication is working fine, problem is only with APP based authentication.

Comment: Sounds like a bug worth reporting to [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact/)

Comment: @samthecodingman I found the issue ,its unity ,actually for input field I was using a asset Modern UI  which takes TextMeshProUGUI type string earlier now i tried traditional UI input field provided by unity which uses Text type string  nd now its working fine ,problem is solved but dont know y this happened.?

Comment: Maybe its related to character encoding? One might have used UTF8 and the other wide character strings or some unexpected ISO standard

Answer (score 0):

I can't say that this is the issue, but in `RegisterUser` you're checking for `task.IsCompleted`. This will always be `true` whether or not the task failed or succeeded (I often use `yield return new WaitUntil(()=>task.IsCompleted);` to wait for async calls in Unity coroutines).

I suspect that there's a chance that you may not have:

Enabled email and password: [image: Screenshot of Email/Password authentication enabled]

[Downloaded your google-services.json](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7015592?hl=en) file.

Or [uploaded your SHA-1](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9137403?hl=en).

Further, if you're testing on mobile, I've definitely had issues with mobile keyboards adding an extra space to your password (especially if you haven't configured the input type). If you've done everything else I listed above, try deleting one character in your username or password after you type it to see if that works.

Finally, if you need a visual walkthrough of any of this. I've created a [Getting started with Firebase Authentication in Unity video](https://youtu.be/52yUcKLMKX0).